# if/case statement in where clause

Tags: sql

in my department paramater my contain a value or one/more department id.

```
SELECT 
    DEPARTMENT,c.DEPTNAME as DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION, c.LOCATION as LOCATION,
    sum(b.qty) as QTY, sum(b.cost) as 'COST', sum(b.nbv) AS 'NBV'
FROM FIX_ASSET A 
right join .SAMPLING b on ASSET_NUMBER=b.ASSET_NUMBER 
left join DEPARTMENT C on A.DEPARTMENT=C.DEPTID 
where BUSINESS_UNIT=1227 and b.year_audit=2016 and taggable='YES'     
group by department, c.DEPTNAME, c.LOCATION
```

What I want is to add a case/if statement inside in `where` clause

```
case when (select count(*) from #tempdept) > 0 
then and fix_asset.department in (select item from #tempdept)
```

if the tempdept data is greater than 0 I would add the condition `And department in(select item from #tempdept)`

Comment: why not always use `fix_asset.department in (...)` even if there's only one of them?

Comment: the department me also contain a null value

Comment: You write a Pseudo Query but you dont explain what is the result you want or the logic.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @VictorBaccal fine. then use something like `where department is null or fix_asset.department in (department)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a case statement for this.  Just make your WHERE clause

```
where BUSINESS_UNIT=1227 and b.year_audit=2016 and taggable='YES'
and (
      (
        (select count(*) from #tempdept) > 0 and fix_asset.department in (select item from #tempdept) 
      )
      or
      (select count(*) from #tempdept) = 0
    )
```

Comment: You could also store the count from #tempdept in a variable and use that variable in the WHERE clause instead.  It might make things look a little neater, and improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this syntax, with two nested `CASE` statements:

```
case when (select count(*) from #tempdept) > 0 
    then 
        case when fix_asset.department in (select item from #tempdept) 
            then 'dosomething'
            else 'dosomething'
        end
    else
        'dosomething'
end AS 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
where BUSINESS_UNIT=1227 and b.year_audit=2016 and taggable='YES'
AND (CASE WHEN (select count(*) from #tempdept) > 0 THEN fix_asset.department IN (select item from #tempdept) ELSE 1 = 1 END)
```

meaning if `count(*)` is greater than 0 then check the `IN` condition, else include the record.